# Lwjgl render only one texture

Tags: java, opengl, textures, minecraft, lwjgl

I'm tryng to create a Minecraft clone, but my code render only one texture, i'm a opengl beginner, some help please?
(I'm italian so excuse me for my bad english)

Here my Texture class

```
private String location;
private int id;
private boolean loaded = false;

public Texture(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public void loadTexture() {
    if (!this.loaded) {
        this.loaded = true;
        try {
            InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("Textures/" + this.location);
            PNGDecoder decoder = new PNGDecoder(stream);
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * decoder.getWidth() * decoder.getHeight());
            decoder.decode(buffer, decoder.getWidth() * 4);
            buffer.flip();
            this.id = GL11.glGenTextures();
            GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.id);
            GL11.glPixelStorei(GL11.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
            GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
            GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
            GL30.glGenerateMipmap(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

my chunk data class that renderize

public class ChunkData {

```
private final Vector3i chunkPos;
private final Block[][][] blocks;

public ChunkData(Vector3i pos) {
    this.chunkPos = new Vector3i(pos);
    this.blocks = new Block[16][16][16];
}

public static boolean inChunk(int x, int y, int z) {
    return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && x < 16 && y < 16 && z < 16;
}

public void setBlockAt(int x, int y, int z, Block block) {
    if (inChunk(x, y, z)) {
        this.blocks[x][y][z] = block;
    }
}

public Block getBlockAt(int x, int y, int z) {
    if (inChunk(x, y, z)) {
        return this.blocks[x][y][z];
    }
    return null;
}

public Vector3i getChunkPos() {
    return this.chunkPos;
}

public void render() {
    blocks[1][1][2].getTexture().loadTexture();
    blocks[2][2][1].getTexture().loadTexture();
}
```

}

there are 2 blocks, one contains this texture

```
@Override
public Texture getTexture() {
    return new Texture("Dirt.png");
}
```

and another is this

```
@Override
public Texture getTexture() {
    return new Texture("Stone.png");
}
```

the blocks[1][1][2] contains a Stone texture and the [2][2][2] a Dirt texture but when i run the program it displays both as a stone texture.

Comment: You need to bind the texture you want to appear on the mesh before drawing the mesh.